# Which file attribute changes when we copy a file from some other user's account?

Tags: linux, unix

Which file attribute changes, when we copy a file from some other user's account?

Comment: Almost all of them, unless you use the `-p` option to preserve attributes.

Comment: @Barmar could you show me, with an example, maybe? would be really helpful.

Comment: Please request your question to be migrated to the correct site. This is not a programming question, so it's off-topic here.

Comment: The owner will be changed to the user who copied the file. The timestamps will all be changed to the current time. Permissions will be set from the current process's `umask`.

Comment: thanks @Barmar that was useful. how can one view the file attributes of a file?

Comment: How little do you know about how to use Unix? That's extremely basic.

Comment: @Barmar I know this one. but this only shows the file permissions. I want to see the attributes.

Comment: It shows the timestamp, owner, group, length.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I am a beginner, as you can guess from my stackoverflow profile.

Comment: Questions about using Unix belong on unix.stackexchange.com. SO is for questions about computer programming.

Comment: Okay I will post there from now on, @Barmar. thanks, but I guess you didn't understand my earlier question, I want to see the file attributes of a file... like...ownerid, group id, etc.

Comment: That's what `ls -l` does. I don't know why it's not working for you.

Comment: You can also use the `stat` command. It takes options that allow you to specify exactly which attributes to show.

Comment: okay, will try out stat. thanks! @Barmar

Comment: @Barmar could you give me the -p preserve attributes command syntax?

Comment: `cp -p old_file new_file`

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is getting really tiresome. This is extremely basic stuff, you can answer that question by reading the man page.

Comment: SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: Dupplicate of U&L : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227451/which-file-attribute-changes-when-we-copy-a-file-from-some-other-users-account